# Why does the size of image change when loading a jpg resource in Android?

Tags: android, resources, size, jpeg

I've created a new Android project and put a `map.jpg` file in the `res/drawable` folder.  Its stats are like this, as reported by `file` command:

```
map.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 200x200, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1000x846, frames 3
```

(Size 1000x846.)

The project uses min SDK version 21 and the target SDK version 24.

I open the file in my class (which is a View subclass) like this (Kotlin):

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.map)
Log.i(TAG, "Our map's size is " + mBitmap.width + "x" + mBitmap.height)
```

Running in the emulator (480x800 hdpi, API level 25) reports the size of the bitmap as 1500x1269, or scaled 1.5x from the size in the file.

Running on a device (Samsung Galaxy A3, API level 24) reports the size of 2000x1692, or scaled 2x.

Why does this happen?  On what does the loaded bitmap's size depend?

(BTW, another way of reading the resource, via `resources.getDrawable()` and `Drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()`, reports the same sizes.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've created a new Android project and put a map.jpg file in the res/drawable folder

That is unlikely to be a good choice of directory.

> Running in the emulator (480x800 hdpi, API level 25) reports the size of the bitmap as 1500x1269, or scaled 1.5x from the size in the file.
>
> Running on a device (Samsung Galaxy A3, API level 24) reports the size of 2000x1692, or scaled 2x.
>
> Why does this happen?

Because you put the image in `res/drawable/`. This is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`. You are saying that this image is designed for `mdpi` screens (around 160dpi). If you do not have other variants of this resource in more-relevant peer directories (e.g., `res/drawable-hdpi/`), Android will scale the resource to accommodate the density of the screen that you are on. Your emulator is an `hdpi` configuration; your Galaxy A3 is an `xhdpi` device.

If you want to say that this image should not be scaled based on density, put it in `res/drawable-nodpi/` or `res/drawable-anydpi/`.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't obvious that the no-suffix version is a synonym for `mdpi` and thus to be scaled; I thought that its role as a "default" source of resources also means it's "not to be touched".

Comment: @Arry: No, sorry. The reason is that the concept of drawable densities was not added until Android 1.5 or 1.6. In Android 1.0 and 1.1, all drawables were in `res/drawable/`. For backwards compatibility, they set up `res/drawable/` as a synonym for the density used by the original Android devices: `mdpi`. That rule has stayed around all these years, again for backwards compatibility. Google doesn't talk about it much and does stupid things in their Android Studio templates that give the impression that `res/drawable/` is for general-purpose stuff.